# Make three random cuts to a circle, what is the expected number of areas produced?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, planar-graphs

For two random cuts, I have 1/3 chance to have 4 and 2/3 chance to have 3. So expectation is 10/3. What about 3 cuts or even n cuts? Are there any general results?

Comment: If this is meant to be a mathematical problem, you should be more careful with definitions. I guess you mean cuts by random straight lines: two of them may dissect a circle into 3 or 4 pieces, indeed. But it's non-trivial to define "random", i.e. a reasonable probability measure on the set of straight lines in a plane.

Comment: What about this https://laurentlessard.com/bookproofs/what-if-robots-cut-your-pizza/ ? It presents some "easy" solutions and then link a research paper at the end for the adventurous ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the crude diagram below, we can see $4$, $5$, $6$, and $7$ areas resulting from $3$ cuts. There is no easy way to tell which is more likely.

[image]